# Why does this C# program will run out of memory in a 64-bits computer with 24GB of memory?

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

This is my code:

> ```
> public class Class1
> {
>     public int[][] binArray;
>     public Class1()
>     {
>         binArray = new int[1000][];
>         for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
>         {
>             binArray[i] = new int[61608];
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        Class1 c2 = new Class1();
        Class1 c3 = new Class1();
        Class1 c4 = new Class1();
        Class1 c5 = new Class1();
        Class1 c6 = new Class1();
        Class1 c7 = new Class1();   // Memory will run out at about this point
        Class1 c8 = new Class1();
        Class1 c9 = new Class1();
        Class1 c0 = new Class1();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Class1 is used to store arrays and I think it will get enough memory fragments of 61608*4 bytes for the 24GB of memory machine, why does it still throw an `out of memory exception` when I initialize the 7th class?

Comment: I also try this on 64bits machine of 8GB and 12GB memory and goes the same result.

Comment: Are you targeting x64 when building?

Comment: Did you compile and run as AnyCPU, x86 or x64?

Answer (score 6):

This is almost certainly because you're building the executable as 32b.  That will still bomb out even when being run on a 64b machine once it exceeds ~3GB of memory.  Compile as 64b and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you, this is the problem, I can go over it now!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you're executing as 32bit.  Each class instance uses about 250mb of memory (1000*61608*4 + overhead), so 7 instances will get into the roughly 1.7gb of memory used.  This is typically where .NET 32bit processes run out of memory, and are no longer able to allocate large fragments.

If you're building in VS 2012, realize that, by default, `AnyCPU` (the default target) will still target x86 since there is a new "Prefer 32bit" option.  Turning that option off will cause `AnyCPU` to build and run as a 64bit process.

Alternatively, you can explicitly target x64 to run as a 64bit process.

Answer (score 1):

some quick back of the envelope calculations on this;

- new int array of 61608 elements. Add 1 for array pointer (stand to be corrected on this), so 61609
- multiply by 1000 = 61609000, add another 1 for array pointer, 61609001
- multiply by 4 as `int` is equivalent to `Int32`, gives 246436004 bytes per `Class1`
- multiply by 7 per instance of `Class1` leaves 1,725,052,028 bytes...approx so we're looking at about 1.6Gbs taken by the arrays alone

Now the application itself is going to take up more space as I'm not accounting for quite a bit. A possible reason for the out of memory exception is due to the paging that may be occurring on the system. The OS makes no guarantee that your program's memory is going to reside in RAM. What are you OS's page file settings?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "gotcha" that one doesn't expect to encounter.

http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2011/02/15/console-application-visual-studio-gotcha-on-x64-os-aspx

or newly updated URL

http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2011/02/15/console-application-visual-studio-gotcha-on-x64-os

"When creating a new Visual C# Console Application in VS2010 for .NET 4.0, the default target settings for the project is to target the x86 platform instead of Any CPU (MSIL) like Visual Studio 2008 does"

Check the properties of your csproj (especially if it is a Console Application)

Comment: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2011/02/15/console-application-visual-studio-gotcha-on-x64-os-aspx link not found

Comment: That is why I pasted the relevant information in my answer.  The stuff inside the quotes.

Comment: Not link in new blog of xavierdecoster ?